# Adjust LazyVGrid to confirm to each GridItem being percentages

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am using the following code to build out a VGrid with 3 columns:

```
    LazyVGrid(columns: [
        GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .top),
        GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .top),
        GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .top)
    ], spacing: 5) {
        locationColumn
        distanceColumn
        hoursColumn
    }
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

What is the best way to adjust each GridItem so that I can have `locationColumn` be 20% at all times, `distanceColumn` be 40% at all times and `hoursColumn` be 40% at all times which equals 100% of the full width view.

All that I'm seeing is minimum and maximum being used as `minimum: 50, maximum: 100` - I want the space to be 100% of the full width at all times with all 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in this code are you even determine what the size of the view is. How are you planning on dividing your columns between the space available?

The simplest way would be to enclose the `LazyVGrid` in a `GeometryReader` and use the size from that.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    LazyVGrid(columns: [
        GridItem(.fixed(geometry.size.width * 0.2), alignment: .top),
        GridItem(.fixed(geometry.size.width * 0.4), alignment: .top),
        GridItem(.fixed(geometry.size.width * 0.4), alignment: .top)
    ], spacing: 5) {
        locationColumn
        distanceColumn
        hoursColumn
    }
}
```

If you happen to know what you want the view width to be, you can simply do:

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [
      GridItem(.fixed(viewWidth * 0.2), alignment: .top),
      GridItem(.fixed(viewWidth * 0.4), alignment: .top),
      GridItem(.fixed(viewWidth * 0.4), alignment: .top)
], spacing: 5) {
      locationColumn
      distanceColumn
      hoursColumn
}
```